# Is the information read in /proc/*pid*/stat updated by a timer interrupt?

Tags: process, cpu, cpu-usage

As documented in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-load.txt the information in the pseudo file /proc/stat is updated by a timer interrupt, which means that /proc/stat may not give a realistic view of the CPU usage.

Is it also the case that the information in /proc/*pid*/stat is also updated by a timer interrupt? If not, how/when is the information therein updated?

Comment: oh, to be frank, this might be very very old documentation and I'm not sure it's true on every platform, and on modern Linux! The reason I say this is because for a long time, the kernel probes infrastructure would allow you to sample time at task entry and exit, instead of the other way around, sample the active task at discrete times. And I'm also not convinced timer interrupts fire the same rate on all cores in SMP systems…

Comment: @MarcusMüller Do you happen to know where I can find information about how or when /proc/pid/stat is updated?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to read `kernel/sched/cputime.c` from the linux kernel, because that contains the function `task_cputime_adjusted` whose value is query when you read `/proc/…/stat`.

Especially the comment for `cputime_adjust` points out that your documentation is questionable to obsolete.

> Adjust tick based cputime random precision against scheduler runtime
> accounting.
>
> Tick based cputime accounting depend on random scheduling timeslices of a
> task to be interrupted or not by the timer.  Depending on these circumstances, the number of these interrupts may be over or under-optimistic, matching the real user and system cputime with a variable precision.
>
> Fix this by scaling these tick based values against the total runtime accounted by the CFS scheduler.
>
> This code provides the following guarantees:
>
> ```c
> stime + utime == rtime                    
> stime_i+1 >= stime_i, utime_i+1 >= utime_i
> ```
>
> Assuming that `rtime_i+1 >= rtime_i`.

So what happens here is that `kernel/sched.c` does update the time spent on a process (in userspace, at lease) whenever it yields for whichever reason; but the statistics are updated once (or less) per system tick. That's of course ambiguous in multi-core systems, so that `cputime_adjust` has to have a spinlock to avoid multiple cores trying to update the same data concurrently.

So, in short: parts of the update is done whenever a process yields control over a CPU core, parts is done every system tick, and only the after a while and making assumptions on the uncorrelatedness of yield instants relative to system ticks do the values shown in /proc/…/stat converge to the actual values.

Comment: thanks for pointing to the relevant source code.